# Using ampersand in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<script>
  var array = ["test1", "test2", "test & test"];
  $(document).ready(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          $("#" + array[i]).hide();
      }
  });
</script>

<ul>
  <li id="test1"></li>
  <li id="test2"></li>
  <li id="test & test"></li>
</ul>
```

While using Javascript/JQuery I want to hide a few parts. 
However, the above code gives me a syntax error.

What do I do so I can compare the id from my listitem with the javascript string?
I already tried switching the ampersand in javascript with things like `"&amp ;"` and `"&#38 ;"`

Since I get the id of the listitem from a database I'd prefer not to change that side.

Comment: An `id` cannot contain white-space characters; as to whether it might work with the white-space removed (making the `id="test&test"`) I'm unsure, though I suspect it would, but you might have to escape the ampersand in your CSS selectors.

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])` and may be followed by any number of letters, digits `([0-9])`, hyphens `("-")`, underscores `("_")`, colons `(":")`, and periods `(".")`.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden that is an old spec and not html5 spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use spaces in the id of an element.

You probably don't want to use an ampersand in the id of an element, but if you really need to you can escape the `&` using one backslash in the css selector, and two backslashes in the jQuery selector.

In your example:

```js
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test\\&test"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $("#" + array[i]).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="test1"></li>
  <li id="test2"></li>
  <li id="test&test"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

id CANNOT contain spaces

replace your id "test & test" with "test_test" and it will work.

```
<ul>
    <li id="test1">a</li>
    <li id="test2">b</li>
    <li id="test_test">c</li>
</ul>
```

and js

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test_test"];
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $("#" + array[i]).hide();
  }

});
```

or if you really need to use ampersand escape it in js array with `\\`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dypehybj/)